# Oracle Select via loop in Stored Procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I'm trying to select data from a table based on a array of filters calculated from another query. I have tried to describe what I'm trying to accomplish 
in pseudo code below.

```
SELECT Equipment, MIN(TIME) as FractionStart, MAX(TIME) as FractionEnd
INTO FRACTIONS
FROM DATA
WHERE ID = 1
GROUP BY (Equipment)

/* Pseudo code */
FOR EACH ROW IN FRACTIONS
  INSERT INTO MYTABLE (SELECT * FROM EVENTTABLE WHERE EVTTIME BETWEEN ROW.FractionStart AND ROW.FractionEnd AND EVTAREA = ROW.Equipment);
FOR NEXT;

RETURN MYTABLE;
```

I have been looking at cursors, but I haven't figured out how I can add rows to them in a loop. Am I looking at the right functions? or is there a better way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
INSERT INTO MYTABLE 
(
SELECT * FROM EVENTTABLE te,  
(
SELECT Equipment, MIN(TIME) as FractionStart, MAX(TIME) as FractionEnd
FROM DATA
WHERE ID = 1
GROUP BY (Equipment)
) td
WHERE te.EVTTIME BETWEEN td.FractionStart AND td.FractionEnd AND te.EVTAREA = td.Equipment
);
```

Comment: Thanks! that was so simple, I'm not sure I understand how it works. (how is the where clause called for each row in the result from DATA table). but it looks like it does the trick.

Comment: You FRACTIONS select cursor is instead represented by a subselect (becoming a table in memory, so to speak), which is then joined to the eventtable via the where condition. You can run them outside insert to see what it is doing.